# APEX 4.2 - Using LOV with Interactive Report

Tags: report, oracle-apex, interactive, lov

now I am using ApEx 4.2 and I want to update my form 
from Classic Report to Interactive Report.
I have a LOV for translating IDs to human readable labels.
But with Interactive Report, I can't configure my form 
using my LOV.

with Classic Report I am successful with:

```
Column attributes for item IDTAXON_DISPLAY
Column attributes: Display as Text(based on LOV, does not save state)
List of Values: Named LOV - Select named LOV
List of values definition:
select artname as DISPLAY_VALUE, idtaxon as RETURN_VALUE from fischart
```

with Interactive Report using a new page I tried:

```
Column attributes for item Idtxon
Column Definition
Display Type: Display as Text(based on LOV, escape special characters)
Column Filter Type Use Defined List of Values to Filter Exact Match
Named List of Values - Select named LOV
List of values definition (Enter a SQL query that returns one column):
select artname as DISPLAY_VALUE, idtaxon as RETURN_VALUE from fischart
```

But I got following error:

```
Named List of Values must be entered for columns with a "Display Type" of
"Based on LOV" or a Column Filter Type which uses a named list of values.
```

I can't see what is wrong. Any idea how to manage this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create List of Values in Shared Components and then it should work. Details below.

1. Go to **Shared Components → List of Values → Create** and create the following:

   - **Create list of values**:  From Scratch
   - **Name**:  Fischart
   - **Type**:  Dynamic
   - **Query**:

     ```
     select artname as DISPLAY_VALUE, idtaxon as RETURN_VALUE from fischart;
     ```
2. Go back to the interactive report and click on the **idtaxon** Column Attributes.
3. Change the following properties:

   - **Display Type**: Display as Text (Based on LOV, escape special characters)
   - **Column Filter Type:** Use Named List of Values to Filter Exact Match
   - **Named list of values:** FISCHART

Comment: Thanks, your solution works for me. Defining a dynamic LOV in **Shared Components** does the trick.